# How to define property choice in json-schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I need to make a Json schema for property choice of object
The first option is:

```
"part_2_2_object_details_array": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "function": {
            "type": "null"
        },
        "address": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "kosfn": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/kosfn"
        }
    }
}
```

The second is:

```
"part_2_2_object_details_array": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "function": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "address": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "kosfn": {
            "type": "null"
        }
    }
}
```

When the function is **null** - kosfn property is an **object**, when function is **string** - kosfn is **null**. But i can't figure out how to build a schema which covers both situations since oneOf can't be applied to properties.

Comment: What do you mean "oneOf can't be applied to properties"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `oneOf` must be an array, where each item is a JSON Schema (subschema).

You need to nest your two schemas into subschemas of `oneOf`...

Live demo: https://jsonschema.dev/s/ssosr

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "kosfn": true
  },
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "function": {
          "type": "null"
        },
        "address": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "kosfn": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/kosfn"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "function": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "address": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "kosfn": {
          "type": "null"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can (and should) extract the definitions which are the same between each subschema, into the parent schema. I've left the two subschemas as you provided them to make it clear what was done.

Comment: yeah, i didn't realized i can make an array of properties and use oneOf. The solution works fine. I think i can generalize those two subschemas.

Comment: Once you think about it as an array of subschemas, where each item in the array is a JSON Schema in its own right, a LOT of JSON Schema becomes easier.

Comment: Schemas (and subschemas) are applied to instances. Applicator keywords determine HOW subschemas are applied, and HOW the results are curated and modified. `properties` is an applicator keyword for example, where each value in the object is itself a subschema.